# jquery mega drop down menu plugin (dcMegaMenu) how to change event hover to click on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

jquery mega drop down menu plugin:
(http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/advanced-styling/)

Hi Guys,
I am working on a responsive website using jquery mega drop down menu plugin by http://www.designchemical.com.

On desktop, by default full width windows (above 980px width) I am using event: "hover" in the plugin option.
But I need a solution on how to change to event: "click" when window size is below 980px width?

Hope to find a solutions here.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this lines:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   if($(window).width() < 980){
      jQuery('#mega-menu').dcMegaMenu({
         event: 'click'
    });
   }
 });
```

Or on window resize:

```
    jQuery(window).resize(function($) {
      if($(window).width() < 980){
        jQuery('#mega-menu').dcMegaMenu({
           event: 'click'
        });
       }
    });
```

Good luck!

Comment: Not working. Have tried. Maybe because on page load, it already load with event: "hover". When resize it still hover event I had already set the $(window).width() < 980.

Comment: ...just reload your page on window resizes. Use $(window).resize() method.

Comment: Had tried. By reload/refresh the page it works fine but not when window resize.

Comment: Is there any way to "kill" dcMegaMenu() then re call it again or something?

Comment: Have no idea, but you can use attr() method to remove your id="megamenu" to 'disable' dcMegaMenu(); and set it back to enable dcMegaMenu() again.

Comment: Had tried remove id. It still runs without that id. I even try change the id attr to different id and it still run the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 600,
            effect: 'slide',
            event: 'click'
        });
```

event:'click' works only with horizontal mega menu.There is no option for click in vertical mega menu.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a function to init the megamenu, depending on width (for this case, if width is more than 966px, the megamenu will be initiated)

```
function init_megamenu() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w >= 966) {
        $('#mega-menu-9').dcMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'fade'
        });
    }
}
```

2) Call the init_megamenu() function on document ready and window resize

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // desktop menu
    init_megamenu();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    // desktop menu
    init_megamenu();
});
```